# How to change text in toolbar button?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a toolbar in my TinyMCE editor. All buttons are correct, but I would like to change the text "Formats" to the Dutch translation "Lettertype".

I tried to add this in the init settings but I guess the toolbar and the menubar are something different:

```
menu: {
    format: {title: 'Lettertype', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'}
}
```

[image: toolbar TinyMCE]

I couldn't find a solution on the web, so how do I change the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are language packs that will translate the entire UI of TinyMCE to other languages.  The packs can be downloaded from here:

https://www.tinymce.com/download/language-packages/

There is a Dutch language pack that (once deployed) should update that button along with the rest of the UI.

If any of the translations don't match your expectation you can modify the js file to meet your needs.